# Hum noise after letting go of the accelerator

Tags: engine, ford, f-150

2001 Ford F-150
250k miles
4.6L 4x4

When I'm on the highway going about 70 and do a "quick release" of the accelerator, the truck makes an audible hum that lasts for about a half a second.  Wondering if that's cause for concern.   Gear box? Transmission?  Just an old truck?

Comment: Old trucks make lots of noises, that is for sure. It could be just about anything. It could just be the drive-train transitioning from power to engine braking. Is this a loud hum? Can you feel it in the vehicle like a shudder or something?

Comment: How old are the tires? Are they about worn out?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Tires are at about 40%

Comment: @CharlieRB I think you might be right about the drive-train.  Is does not cause a shutter in steering but just feedback to the pedal and that short hum/buzz.

Comment: Check your u-joints to ensure there's absolutely no slop in them. Also, thinking it might be the differential making the transition between being loaded and unloaded. If you haven't done it in a while (or never done it) you might consider changing out the diff fluid in both the front and rear. Might clear this up, but is probably needed anyway if it's never been changed anyway.